# What does source do in kendo-scheduler's base-edit.service do?

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, rxjs, kendo-scheduler

I'm trying to understand the edit service example ([link](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/scheduler/api/BaseEditService/)) in kendo-ui for angular for the scheduler (which is in beta). The EditService class extends the BaseEditService.

The read() function for the editService in my code looks like this:

```
public read(): void {
    if (this.data.length) {
        this.source.next(this.data);
        return;
    }

    this.fetch().subscribe(data => {
        this.data = data.map(item => this.readEvent(item));
        this.source.next(this.data);
    },null, null
    );
}
```

I don't understand what the *this.source.next(this.data)* does.

According to the base-edit.service.d.ts:

```
/**
* The source subject for the `events` observable.
*/
protected source: BehaviorSubject<TEvent[]>;
```

Drilling deeper the BehaviorSubject (from RxJS) reveals a comment

```
* A variant of Subject that requires an initial value and emits its current
* value whenever it is subscribed to.
```

I'm beginning to think that this.data is needed to feed into into this.source.next() and the reason its not done in one line like the following

```
 this.source.next(data.map(item => this.readEvent(item)));
```

is because its needed for the if statement when the data already exists.